# C# MVC 3-step Bootstrap layout, Next button triggers required fields to error validation

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not sure how to explain this exactly in correct terms, but I can do my best!

So what happens is, this is the code for the cshtml next button for a checkout page we're trying to make.

```
<button id="activate-step-2" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
```

The page goes through step 1 (user details) through to step 2 (shipping info) and 3 (payment info).
The issue is, none of the fields are listed as 'required' in their respective @html lines. When you click with all empty fields in step 1, you get thrown back to step 1 after a flicker of step 2 page, and with the validation summary showing that every other field NOT included in step 1 (other fields: shipping info and payment info) are empty and need to be filled in.

Clearly, it's doing something, submitting info, or something of the sorts.
Also, this error is triggered if you make one or more of the fields in step 1 'required' in the @html lines and then fill out all the 'required' fields and hit Next. It will trigger the same error!

If you leave all 'required' properties unmentioned/off, then you get the same error either way. It's so strange and I have no clue what is happening.

I am a bit of a noob to MVC, but my partner who's working with me on the project is a bit more knowledgeable. Please post what you think might help us solve this problem, I am sure there's a solution for this somewhere!

Comment: You're clicking on a button within a form so it is going to validate all fields within the form.  If you are making a multipage form that is on a single page, you may want to think about ajax loading each step in as you press the next button, this way only the current form is validated or wrap each separate step in their on html.begin form

Comment: Thanks Pete, but Jelle Oosterbosch already had the answer I needed ^_^

Comment: That wrapping thing btw, might come in handy later. So thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the default value for the type attribute of a button is "submit". So you should make this

```
<button id="activate-step-2" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Next</button>
```